Catalog search - Elasticsearch
How can I optimize searches on the page using Elasticsuite, without increasing this limit in the config Catalog - Catalog Search - Minimal Query Length.
It is currently set to 10, and if it is low, it affects the performance of the site. If I search for something under 10 characters, it returns something random that has nothing to do with it.
I want to optimize the searches and get them according to the brand the first time. If I'm looking for a certain brand, bring me the products of that brand.
Can anyone help me or has anyone done something similar?
